# Error in SSIS Lookup Connection Definition

Tags: sql, ssis, navision

I am getting an error message in SSIS when trying to create a lookup transform.

OLD DB connection manager is defined.
I am selecting to write a query:

```
select 
    [No_] as a, 
    CASE isnumeric([name 2])
     WHEN 1 THEN convert(int, [name 2])
     ELSE -1
    END as abcId

from 
    [Company Name$vendor]
```

I get this error message:
"Must specify valid information for parsing in the string"

If I click on preview I see the results that I want to use for the lookup, so the query is correct.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've come across this error before. Sometime just by deleting the lookup and creating a new one it goes away. It may be metadata issue.

Comment: I'm able to create a table that matches what you've supplied and use the above query in a lookup task. Perhaps you've over-simplified the problem domain?

Comment: What does Navision have to do with this question?   Are you developing in an environment other than BIDS?

Comment: This query is from navision db, so I thought maybe navision developers might have seen it before.